# Junit test cases for @PreAuthorise in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have tried implemeting junit test cases for this below function but getting issue Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@securityService.isValidUser(#id)'

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.isValidUser(#id)")
    @GetMapping(path = "/account", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> account(final @RequestParam(name = "id") String id, final @RequestParam(name = "sec") String sec) throws AssetSystemException, UserNotFoundException {
        userService.unLockUserAccount(sec);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Junit testcases:

```
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration
class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
SecurityService securityService;
@Test
    void accountTest() throws Exception {
        when(securityService.isValidUser("test.test@gmail.com")).thenReturn(true);

        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/account?id=789988&sec=test@123").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Origin", "*")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: Where do you initialize `securityService` ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe changed and added a SecurityService

Comment: Use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not working

Comment: It isn't working how? Different error? same error? Or ...

Comment: @Deinum same error